# shell script に対して tagging を行えるような tag システムはありますか？

Tags: shellscript

例えば、 C++ などであれば、 GNU Tags などがあって、これをエディタに組み込むなどによって function の索引を作成し、そこにジャンプすることができます。
shellscript に対して、同じことをやりたいと思いました。

https://www.gnu.org/software/global/ を見たいたのですが、 shell script は supported の項目に含まれていませんでした。

### 質問

shell script に対して tagging を行えるような tag システムはありますか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exuberant Ctags は shellscript (Bourne/Korn/Z) に対応しています。

http://ctags.sourceforge.net/languages.html